# Compare one array with another and replace missing values php

Tags: php, arrays, replace, compare

I have two Arrays:

```
$a1=array("Maths","English","Science","ICT");
$a2=array("Maths","ICT");
```

I want to compare $a1 with $a2, then return

```
$a3=array("Maths",",,",",,","ICT");
```

So replace the missing values  in $a2 with ",,"

This is my meager attempt :(

```
$a1=array("Maths","English","Science","ICT");
$a2=array("Maths","ICT");
$result = array_diff($a1, $a2);
foreach ($result as $v){
$a3 = str_replace($v, ",,", $a1);
}
print_r($a3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you figured it out, but I think this might work better:

```
<?php

$a1 = array("Maths", "English", "Science", "ICT");
$a2 = array("Maths", "ICT");

$a3 = $a1;

$keys = array_keys(array_diff($a1, $a2));
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $a3[$key] = ',,';

print_r($a3);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/30e32e02a5491a):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Maths
    [1] => ,,
    [2] => ,,
    [3] => ICT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks if you looked:

```
$a1=array("Maths","English","Science","ICT");
$a2=array("Maths","ICT");

$result = array_diff($a1, $a2);

foreach ($result as $v){

$v = str_replace($result, ",,", $a1);

}
print_r($v);
```

Comment: This won't work if you have a subject called `Biochemistry` and `chemistry`. [Example](https://eval.in/private/60d2b8380fa020).

Comment: I just encountered that exact problem with "English" and "English Lit" any ideas?

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at my answer. It will work even if the subject contains parts of other subjects.